# timer cannot be added as a control in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, timer

why does this gives error: `this.Controls.Add(timer1);`

but this doesn't : `this.Controls.Add(button1);`

When both , the button and timer are controls then why can't we add the timer as a control in winforms?

Comment: Which **kind** of a timer are you using? There are at least three different `Timer` classes in the .NET framework ....

Comment: timer control don't have GUI.

Comment: Yes more specifically a timer is a **Component** and not a **Control**.

Comment: am talking about : System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: see my answer. That ain't a control either, its a component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, `Timer` inherits directly from `Component`, and not through `Control` as `Button` does:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new Timer();
this.components.Add(timer);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

There are three Timers in .NET:

- [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). : Lightweight timer not recommended for WinForms. This inherits from MarshalByRefObject. (Not a Component or Control)
- [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx). : Server based timer with extra features. This inherits from [Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx).
- [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx). : Recommended for windows forms. Also inherits from [Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx).

**None** of them are **controls**.

All [container controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.aspx) have a [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) property which exposes a [ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx), which takes only a [System.Windows.Forms.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) (or classes that inherit)

See [ContainerControl.Controls.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add.aspx)